# use navigation drawer in all activities in my project

Tags: java, android

I have created a navigation drawer in my AbstractActivity.class and i want to use that drawer in all my activities , so i created another drawer class and extending that class in another activity but it isnt working , can anyonetell me whats wrong in my code ?

Abstractactivity.class

```
package com.astro.famouspandit.Activities.Abstract;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.astro.famouspandit.Activities.Activity.ChartStyle;
import com.astro.famouspandit.Activities.Activity.Contact;
import com.astro.famouspandit.Activities.Activity.Settings;
import com.astro.famouspandit.Activities.Activity.Welcome;
import com.astro.famouspandit.R;

public class AbstractActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;
    private LinearLayout mDrawerList;
    protected DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    protected ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    protected Toolbar toolbar;
    protected FrameLayout framelayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_abstract);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        framelayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.content_frame);


        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle().toString();
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close){

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }


        };



        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);


    }

    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {

        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_Aboutus).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;


    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        switch(position) {
            case 1:
                Intent a = new Intent(this, Welcome.class);
                startActivity(a);
                break;
            case 2:
                Intent b = new Intent(this, Welcome.class);
                startActivity(b);
                break;
            default:
        }
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        int items = item.getItemId();
        switch(items){

            case R.id.action_Settings:{
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,Settings.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }break;

            case R.id.action_Contact_us:{
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,Contact.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }break;

            case R.id.action_Aboutus:{
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,ChartStyle.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }break;

            case R.id.action_Profile:{
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,ChartStyle.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

activity_abstract.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"

        android:background="#0F6177">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/navigation_drawer"></include>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

NavigationActivity.class

```
package com.astro.famouspandit.Activities.Abstract;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewStub;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.astro.famouspandit.R;

public abstract class NavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    protected DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private LinearLayout mFrameLayout_HeaderView;
    protected FrameLayout mFrameLayout_ContentFrame;
    protected ActionBarDrawerToggle mActionBarDrawerToggle;
    protected Toolbar mToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);

        mFrameLayout_ContentFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_content_frame);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        mFrameLayout_HeaderView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        mFrameLayout_HeaderView.setOnClickListener(this);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_DrawerLayout);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        mDrawerLayout.setStatusBarBackground(R.color.colorPrimary);

        mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle
                (
                        this,
                        mDrawerLayout,
                        mToolbar,
                        R.string.drawer_open,
                        R.string.drawer_close
                ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                // Disables the burger/arrow animation by default
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, 0);
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mActionBarDrawerToggle);

        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        }
        mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

    }


}
```

activity_navigationactivity.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_DrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_activity_content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <include layout="@layout/navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

class where i am extending NavigationActivity Class

```
public class Welcome extends NavigationActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private CardView mAstro,mMatch,mPanch,mAsk,mContact;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_welcome,mFrameLayout_ContentFrame);
```

Comment: Please specify what isn't working

Comment: the best way for use is use fragment in main activity with one navigation drawer for all if not you have to declare drawer layout repeat on every activity you want.

Comment: @user3425867 when i run my app the navigationdrawer is not displaying on the activity where i am extending it i.e the Welcome class nothing appears

Comment: @GiapLee can you tell me how it is done ?

Comment: i mean: you should use only main activity which have a set of fragments. because fragment inside a activity main layout so them have drawer navigation from their parent

Comment: @GiapLee my code is working but it hides my activity content and the drawer on click isnt working!

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly common question has been blogged about. Essentially, you want to create a BaseActivity with a layout that contains the Navigation Drawer and then have your other Activities extend the BaseActivity and inflate their layouts within the BaseActivity's layout. This way you have the Navigation Drawer in all your activity and reuse the code for setting up the Drawer (since that code lives in the BaseActivity).

You can find an example implementation along with a more detailed explanation here: http://lucas-dev.com/blog/entry/base-activities-sliding-menu.html